# Prove that $\sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} + \sqrt[3]{c} \ge ab + bc + ca$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, symmetric-polynomials, holder-inequality, uvw

For all positive $a,b,c $ satisfying $a+b+c = 3$,Prove:
$$
\sum_{cyc} \sqrt[3]{a} \ge \sum_{cyc} ab
$$

This is a hard problem and I tried it myself, but it's really hard without using advanced techniques(e.g. EV theorem or HCF theorem).

Is there any easy way without computer and HCF to this problem?

---

(Updated) Sorry for that I posted this in a hurry. I will show you more in this updated part.

First of all, HCF kills it.(If you don't know it, click [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257869014_An_extension_of_Jensen%27s_discrete_inequality_to_half_convex_functions)) Consider
$$
2\sum_{cyc} ab = (\sum_{cyc} a)^2 - \sum_{cyc} a^2 = 9 - \sum_{cyc} a^2
$$
Thus, we only need to prove
$$
\sum_{cyc} (a^2 + 2 \sqrt[3]{a}) \ge 9
$$
or
$$
\sum_{cyc} f(a) \ge 9
$$
where $f(x)=x^2 + 2\sqrt[3]{x}$. And because $f''(x)=2-\frac{4}{9\sqrt[3]{x^5}}$, Thus we know $f(x)$ is convex on $\left [ \frac{\sqrt[5]{8}}{3\sqrt[5]{3}}, 3\right)$. So by HCF theorem we only need to prove when $b=a$,$c=3-2a$ or
$$
6a^2 - 12a + 9 + 4\sqrt[3]{a} +2 \sqrt[3]{3-2a} \ge 9
$$
The rest is easy with derivative.

Second, a friend of mine told me that using tangent line can solve it. But I didn't see how that's relevant.

Third, I found this problem on the Internet, but I'm sure I've solved it or saw the solution to it before.

Comment: Alternative proof: Using AM-GM, we have $\sqrt[3]{a} = \frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{a \cdot a \cdot 1}} \ge \frac{a}{(a + a + 1)/3} = \frac{3a}{2a + 1}$. It suffices to prove that $\frac{3a}{2a + 1} + \frac{3b}{2b + 1} + \frac{3c}{2c + 1} \ge ab + bc + ca$. Then use pqr method.

Comment: I think we need to open this topic. I checked, EV and HCF indeed help. Also, we can use the Vasc's RCF Theorem. I think it's very interesting to find a solution without using these theorems like the beautiful River Li's solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It is nice to see it reopened. My proof is not nice actually but not complicated.

Comment: @River Li Post please your full solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I posted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, TL method does not help here.

Another way.

Let $a=x^3$, $b=y^3$ and $c=z^3$.

Thus, $x^3+y^3+z^3=3$ and we need to prove that:
$$x+y+z\geq x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^3$$ or
$$(x+y+z)^3(x^3+y^3+z^3)^5\geq243(x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^3)^3.$$
Now, let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where
$$f(w^3)=u^3(9u^3-9uv^2+w^3)^5-(9v^6-9uv^2w^3+w^6)^3.$$
But, $$f'(w^3)=5u^3(9u^3-9uv^2+w^3)^4+2(9uv^2-2w^3)(9v^6-9uv^2w^3+w^6)^2\geq0,$$ which says that $f$ increases and it's enough to prove our inequality for the minimal value of $w^3$.

Now, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive roots of the equation
$$(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)=0$$ or
$$t^3-3ut^2+3v^2t-w^3=0,$$ which says that a graph of $f(t)=t^3-3ut^2+3v^2t$ and the line $g(t)=w^3$ have three common points.

But $$f'(t)=3t^2-6ut+3v^2=3(t-(u+\sqrt{u^2-v^2}))(t-(u-\sqrt{u^2-v^2})),$$
which gives $t_{min}=u+\sqrt{u^2-v^2}$ and since $f(0)=0$, we obtain two cases:

1. $f\left(t_{min}\right)>0$.

In this case $w^3$ gets a minimal value, when the line $g(t)=w^3$ is a tangent line to the graph of $f$, which says that in this case it's enough to prove our inequality for equality case of two variables.

We'll prove this for the inequality $$(x+y+z)^3(x^3+y^3+z^3)^5\geq243(x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^3)^3.$$
It's enough to assume $y=z=1$ and we need to prove that:
$$(x+2)^3(x^3+2)^5\geq243(2x^3+1)^3$$ or $h(x)\geq0,$ where
$$h(x)=3\ln(x+2)+5\ln(x^3+2)-3\ln(2x^3+1)-5\ln3.$$
But $$h'(x)=\frac{(x-1)(3x^5+7x^4+7x^3+6x^2-x-1)}{(x+2)(x^3+2)(2x^3+1)},$$
which gives $x_{min}=1$, $x_{max}=0.375...$ and since $h(1)=0$ it's enough to prove that $h(0)\geq0$ or $256\geq243,$ which is true.

2. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $z\rightarrow0^+$ and $y=1$.

Thus, we need to prove that $$(x+1)^3(x^3+1)^5\geq243x^9,$$ which is true by AM-GM because $256>243.$

Answer (score 2):

*pqr method*:

Using AM-GM, we have
$$\sqrt[3]{a} = \frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{a \cdot a \cdot 1}} \ge \frac{a}{(a + a + 1)/3} = \frac{3a}{2a + 1}.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{3a}{2a + 1} + \frac{3b}{2b + 1} + \frac{3c}{2c + 1} \ge ab + bc + ca.$$

Let $p = a + b + c = 3, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{36r + 12q + 3p}{8r + 4q + 2p + 1} \ge q$$
or
$$(q + 1)(9 - 4q) + (36 - 8q)r \ge 0.$$

If $9 - 4q \ge 0$, since $q \le p^2/3 = 3$,
the inequality is true.

If $9 - 4q < 0$, using $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9} = \frac{4}{3}q - 3$ (Schur's inequality), it suffices to prove that
$$(q + 1)(9 - 4q) + (36 - 8q)\cdot \left( \frac{4}{3}q - 3\right) \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac{11}{3}(4q - 9)(3 - q) \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy by considering using Hölder inequality, which can remove roots effectively.
First we homogenise it, we need to prove
$$
(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a})^3(\sum_{cyc} a )^5 \ge 3^5(\sum_{cyc}ab)^3
$$
By Hölder we have
$$
(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a})^3(\sum_{cyc} a )^5 \ge (\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{a^3})^8
$$
So, we only need to prove
$$
(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{a^3})^8 \ge 243 (\sum_{cyc}ab)^3
$$
This is the well-known 243-inequality (by Harazi on AOPS).
$$
(\sum_{cyc} x^3)^8 \ge 243(\sum_{cyc} x^4y^4)^3
$$
(In case you didn't notice, this can be proved directly from A-G inequality)

Comment: I think, it's not harazi's inequality. It's the Vasc's inequality.